# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck and works slowly on Lenovo ideapad

Tags: drivers, lenovo

I bought a new Lenovo ideapad 720s-15.
i ran the live cd on it and it worked well except it got stuck when i restarted or powered off. i figured this issue will be solved after the installation and after ill setup the system with the right drivers.
after installation it was working really slowly.
i switched to the nvidia driver, it got faster, but the reboot problem stayed.
the weird thing is that the leptop works perfectly in recovery mode.
any ideas?